# send data from app engine(python) to remote server (linux with php)

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine

Is it possible to send data from app engine server to another,external server with httpd service?   I don't care if the payload will be 1 bit, I just need to make this happen.

I checked all over the place and found this:
"
Can't Open Sockets To Arbitrary Ports 
Given that Google App Engine is a constrained runtime environment, it has an understandable limitation of preventing you from opening sockets on arbitrary ports. This restriction is necessary for security and scalability and Google can only be expected to enable these scenarios by providing their own wrapper libraries for each desired scenario. However, this leads to restrictions on important scenarios. For example, if your application wants to incorporate email and connect to an IMAP server, then you have no ability to do this on GAE.

While Google does plan to eventually add additional services to their capabilities, there is no plan for providing a general capability for opening sockets. 
"
in [here](http://www.sachinrekhi.com/blog/2009/08/17/shortcomings-of-google-app-engine)

and from here, I have a new question: Is it possible to keep a connection from my linux service to app engine(the other way around) ? if my linux was a android device, it would be possible. can my server pretend to be android device that will listen to events from the server? I implemented push notification on app engine and i have another server for push for iPhones, when the app engine sends to all, i need the linux to know about it and to send to all iphones as well.
thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two questions:

> Is it possible to send data from app engine server to another,external
>   server with httpd service?

Yes, you can have make outgoing http connections from your GAE app ([link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview)).

> Is it possible to keep a connection from my linux service to app
>   engine(the other way around) ?

You can if you use [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/) to stream events to your linux. If I remember correctly you'll just have to request a new connection token every hour.